# Forwarding UDP to TCP with socat shows connection refused

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, socat

I use this command as I googled, to create a TCP port and forward requests of this port to its UDP:

```
socat tcp4-listen:1995,reuseaddr,fork UDP:nameserver:1994
```

And `netstat -tulpn | grep 199` shows they're both accessible.

But the issue is when I want to connect to 1995, I get error `connection refused`, but I can directly connect to 1994.

And in the application I can change `udp:1994` to `tcp:1994` and it works fine too.

The only issue is when I try to open a TCP port to forward requests to UDP.

I also enabled port forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
root@vps-19d20a39:~# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```